# How to convert char in UTF-16 encoding to char in CP855 encoding?

Tags: java, android, encoding

For example, I have `char a = "п"`, and I want to get cyrillic ascii value of it, is it possible?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "cyrillic ascii"?

Comment: Java provides several facilities for encoding characters, and it's unclear what the most appropriate one would be for your particular case.  Two reasonable alternatives would would be using an `OutputStreamWriter` and using `String.toBytes()` -- in both cases, specifying the wanted charset rather than relying on the default (unless, of course, you can rely on the default being then encoding you want).

Comment: I meant cp855 charset

Answer (score 1):

To convert a text from one encoding to another you can use `java.nio.Charset` class:

```
byte[] data = // your encoded data in UTF-16
Charset from = StandardCharsets.UTF_16;
Charset to = // cyrillic charset
byte[] converted = to.encode(from.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(data))).array();
```

Comment: Yes. `char` in anything other than UTF-16 is not Java. `byte[]` can hold text in other character encodings.